# update one list instead of duplicating it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, html-lists

I have a list of names with points assigned to each one, each time i click on a button related to that name it adds a point then it ranks them in the html file when pressing the `rank` button, everything works fine but when i make changes and click rank again it adds another list instead of updating the existing one:

```
let characters = [
   {name: document.getElementById("name 1").textContent, points: 0},
   {name: document.getElementById("name 2").textContent, points: 0},
   {name: document.getElementById("name 3").textContent, points: 0}
];

function choice (button) {
   const buttonCharacterObject = characters.find(obj => obj.name === button.textContent);
   buttonCharacterObject.points += 1;
   const ranking = characters.sort((a, b) => (a.points < b.points ? 1 : -1));
   console.log(ranking);
}

function rank() {
   characters.forEach(function (character) {   
      document.getElementById('rank').innerHTML += '<li>' + character.name + '</li>
})}

<button id="name 1" onclick="choice(this)">Martin</button>
<button id="name 2" onclick="choice(this)">Sam</button>
<button id="name 3" onclick="choice(this)">John</button>
<button onclick="rank()">Rank Characters</button>
<ol id="rank">
    
</ol>
```

Comment: "it adds another list" doesn't it just push another `<li>` elementes inside the `<ol id="rank">` list?

Comment: @Jan Stránský yes sorry for not explaining it well, it goes :

1- name 1,
2- name 2,
3- name 3,
4- name 1,
5- name 2,
6- name 3

Comment: Then it just follows what you ask the program to do. Inside `rank()` function, clear the content of the `ol` before `characters.forEach`

Comment: and how do i do that ?

Comment: `.innerHTML=""`

Comment: Thank you! appreciate the help, it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed below the question, the problem was that list items were being added and the existing items remained. The solution was to clear the list beforehand:

```js
function rank() {
   var el = document.getElementById('rank')
   el.innerHTML = ""
   characters.forEach(function (character) {   
      el.innerHTML += '<li>' + character.name + '</li>
})}
```

Comment: yes, i'm very new to this that's why i couldn't guess it, is it okay if i write the code like this ? although yours is much neater:



`function rank() {
   document.getElementById('rank').innerHTML = "";
   characters.forEach(function (character) {   
      document.getElementById('rank').innerHTML += '<li>' + character.name + '</li>';
})}`

Comment: Depends on definition of okay :-) The code works, so it may be okay. From **my** point of view it is not okay. The code duplication (`document.getElementById('rank')`) is error prone and harder to maintain (e.g. changing id from `'rank'`, you would need to change it at 2 places, while with the "`el`-approach" only at one place)

Comment: okay i will do as u suggested, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Just to make it clear, I just wrote here **my** opinion (and emphasized that is it my opinion). Although I am concerned that is is a good opinion :-) it is not a dogma